# Custom IFC export settings for Autodesk Platform Services Model Derivative?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm aware that I can select the `exportSettingName` in the IFC conversion config as described [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api) but this must be a configuration already present in the Revit model.

Is there no way to add my own custom config when I create the conversion job?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your IFC export settings are created with a Revit IFC exporter version greater than v22.1.1.0, then it's unsupported, unfortunately. The newer IFC exporter version uses JSON-based IFC export settings, and we have a wishlist Item, RVTLMV-3166, for adding this support.

A workaround is to use Design Automation API for Revit to export IFC instead. Here is an example: https://github.com/yiskang/aps-revit-ifc-exporter-appbundle

Or you could try to convert the JSON-based IFC export settings to the legacy one using Revit API. Here is an example and code snippet:

```cs
// https://github.com/yiskang/aps-revit-ifc-exporter-appbundle/blob/main/RevitIfcExporter/IFC/IFCExportConfigurationsUtils.cs#L29


var exportSettingName = "MY IFC2x3 CV2.0";

var configurationsMap = new IFCExportConfigurationsMap();
configurationsMap.AddSavedConfigurations(document);

IFCExportConfigurationsUtils.ConvertSavedConfigurationsFromJsonToLegacy(document)

var exportConfig = configurationsMap[exportSettingName];

var exportOptions = new IFCExportOptions();
exportConfig.UpdateOptions(doc, exportOptions, filterViewId);
```

**Note. As the above are samples, that means we don't have enough tests covered. Before using the sample codes on your models, please do the necessary tests with those sample codes.**

Comment: Thanks Eason, I'll look into the Design Automation route for now but it would definitely be nice to be able to simply pass a custom IFC export config in Model Derivative using nothing but JSON.

Comment: @VincentCadoret Hope you doing well. What is your main Revit version you want to export IFC from?

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang, the main versions of Revit tend to be the versions of Revit currently supported by Autodesk (2024 to 2021), but even if it was only 2024 that would already be a big improvement.

Comment: Thanks @VincentCadoret for sharing the version info. I will share that with our engineering team for evaluating the RVTLMV-3166. Thanks again!